# Register plotly dash callbacks after app.run_server() without having to reload webpage?

Tags: python, callback, plotly-dash

I have built a dash app where new visualizations can be loaded on demand from python classes.
For static content without callbacks, this is working fine.

When trying to load callbacks, these are not active when first calling the page. Only after having reloaded the webpage once, the on-demand content works as expected.

[image]

My best guess is that this is caused by registering the callback *after* having executed `app.run_server()`. Preloading however is not an option, as the classes in my application require additional input arguments, which are only known during runtime of the server.

So my question is: Does anyone know a way how to successfully register callbacks after the server is already running? Or another way to achieve the same behaviour?

Here is my approach so far, comparing preloaded behaviour to on-demand behaviour:

```py
from dash import Dash, html, dcc, Input, Output


class OnDemandContent:

    def __init__(self):
        # prefix to distinguish on-demand from preloaded components
        self.prefix = self.__class__.__name__
        # registering a class method as a callback,
        # from https://community.plotly.com/t/putting-a-dash-instance-inside-a-class/6097/4
        app.callback(Output(f'{self.prefix}counter', 'children'),
                     Input(f'{self.prefix}interval', 'n_intervals'))(self.update)

    def get_layout(self):
        return html.Div([
            html.Div(['Counter has not started yet'], id=f'{self.prefix}counter'),
            dcc.Interval(id=f'{self.prefix}interval', interval=100),
        ])

    def update(self, n_clicks):
        return f'Counting: {n_clicks}'


class PreloadedContent(OnDemandContent):
    pass

# callback exceptions are suppressed, because some elements are loaded on demand
app = Dash(__name__, suppress_callback_exceptions=True)

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Div('Preloaded Content is not shown yet', id='content-preloaded'),
    html.Button('Show PreloadedContent', id='show-preloaded', n_clicks=0),
    html.Hr(),
    html.Div('OnDemandContent is not shown yet', id='content-on-demand'),
    html.Button('Show OnDemandContent', id='show-on-demand', n_clicks=0),
])

# initialize preload class and hence activate its callbacks before running the server.
# in my app, this is not an option, because the class would require further input
# which is given by the user during runtime
preloaded_instance = PreloadedContent()

# callbacks for "show x" buttons
@app.callback(
    Output('content-on-demand', 'children'),
    Input('show-on-demand', 'n_clicks'),
    prevent_initial_call=True,
)
def update_output(_):
    return OnDemandContent().get_layout()

@app.callback(
    Output('content-preloaded', 'children'),
    Input('show-preloaded', 'n_clicks'),
    prevent_initial_call=True,
)
def update_output(_):
    return preloaded_instance.get_layout()


app.run_server(port=80, debug=True)
```

Comment: You can’t add callbacks at runtime at Dash. However, you can achieve some dynamic behavior by using pattern matching callbacks. https://dash.plotly.com/pattern-matching-callbacks

Comment: @emher thanks for the suggestion, but I would still need to register these pattern matching callbacks before running the server, which would greatly limit their flexibility. I was hoping that there still is some sort of registering opportunity after running the server, such as app.refresh_server or something alike (which I also could not find, so you might be right that it's not possible)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having thought about my idea of customized instances with the information that registering callbacks at runtime will not be possible (one of the rare occasions where "it cannot be done" pushed me in the right direction), I saw that it is more a matter of a redesign of my approach:

Instead of completely instantiating the classes when I need them, I instead instantiate them without customization before running the server (hence registering the callbacks at the correct time), and only modify this instance with custom content via its `get_layout()` method during runtime.

[image]

Here's the modified code:

```py
from dash import Dash, html, dcc, Input, Output, State


class PreloadedContent:

    def __init__(self):
        app.callback(Output(f'counter', 'children'),
                     Input(f'interval', 'n_intervals'))(self.update)

    def get_layout(self, custom_content):
        self.custom_content = custom_content
        return html.Div([
            html.Div(['Counter has not started yet'],
                     id=f'counter'),
            dcc.Interval(id=f'interval', interval=100),
        ])

    def update(self, n_clicks):
        return f'Counting with {self.custom_content}: {n_clicks}'


# callback exceptions are suppressed, because some elements are loaded on demand
app = Dash(__name__, suppress_callback_exceptions=True)

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Div('Preloaded Content is not shown yet', id='content-preloaded'),
    html.Hr(),
    dcc.Input(id="input", placeholder="customize instance"),
    html.Hr(),
    html.Button('Show PreloadedContent', id='show-preloaded', n_clicks=0),
])

preloaded_instance = PreloadedContent()


@app.callback(
    Output('content-preloaded', 'children'),
    Input('show-preloaded', 'n_clicks'),
    State('input', 'value'),
    prevent_initial_call=True,
)
def update_output(_, custom_content):
    return preloaded_instance.get_layout(custom_content)


app.run_server(port=80, debug=True)
```